# AdColony keeps downloading video ads and store them on android device

Tags: android, ads, adcolony

I'm developing android apps and using AdColony SDK to display video ads. The problem I found is that it keeps downloading video ads and store them on my device.

I used `adb shell` to have a deep inspect of the file system on my android device. In folder `/data/data/com.package.name/`, there is a folder called `files/adc/media`, which stores a number of `png` and `m4v` files. Those `m4v` files are the video ads (15 or 30 seconds long).

Initially, when I install my app and launch it for the first time, there were 2 video ads in that folder, but after a play with the app a while, there are more video ads being downloaded and stored there. Some of the videos might be 10MB large. And when I go to device settings->applications->my app, the Data grows to 45MB and seems like it just keeps growing!

I bet even if I could delete them, it will download these videos again. So is there any way to stop it from downloading video ads? Or can I set a max number of video ads it is allowed to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdColony does cache our assets to the device - both for quality (instant loading advertisements) as well as reusability. Many assets are shared across multiple campaigns and in the case that a duplicate advertisement is served it saves you from re-downloading the same assets.

Each device has a specific memory class (or app specific memory limit) that we will not exceed, and we also purge old and unused assets occasionally to keep the size down.

While it is possible to programmatically clear your app's data cache, we do not recommend this  as it may lead to redundant downloads and unnecessary data usage.

Please feel free to contact us further at support@adcolony.com.

Comment: cool thx, i've never expected people from adcolony answering my question. so is there a way to know the specific memory limit of a device? also, if i have multiple apps that are using adcolony, is it possible to share these assets across them?

Comment: No problem! You can access the memory class through the ActivityManager's [getMemoryClass() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29). Our assets are stored within the app's data cache and as such are not shared between multiple apps.